# Got Undefined when accessing a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have tried accessing the Vue components in my Vue file.

```
<template>
    {{this.tables}}
</template>


export default {
name: 'test',
data() {
    return {

    }
},

computed:{
    tables() {
        console.log(this.$children);

    },
}
```

When I use `console.log(this.$children);` following is the result
[image]

Now, I want to access and get the items of `display_table` from `$children` vuecomponent. So I use `console.log(this.$children[0]);` but this one returns `undefined`. Can someone give me some insights on what should I do to get the items in `display_table`?

Comment: Anyone can please help me on this? Thanks

Comment: @Reiner I've already tried doing `console.log(this.$.refs);` but this returns an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'refs' of undefined"`

Comment: What you're likely seeing is the result of the component's render function not being compiled, but the program continuing to run and then adding it immediately after. [Read this for an explanation from a core Vue member](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-this-refs-key-returns-undefined-when-it-really-is/1226/2)

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I've already read that earlier, but still can't get the concept :S :S

Comment: Its comes down to timing and just a few milliseconds. Try wrapping the log statement in `nextTick(() => { console.log(this.$.refs) })`

Comment: Where should I put this :S I've tried putting it under `computed` inside `tables()`, it says : `nextTick is not defined`.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Ok. I have already figured out in dealing with the error. My problem now is if I do `nextTick(() => { console.log(this.$children[0].display_table) })`, it now returns an empty array.

Comment: It's actually `this.$nextTick()`, my bad I should have clarified that.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? In general, you should not be using the DOM as a data source, you should be looking at the data in your viewmodel.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter The same problem. when doing this one `console.log(this.$children[0].display_table)`

Comment: @RoyJ I want to get the items in `display_table`, specifically the `area_id`.

Comment: I think you should customize `display_table` to do what you want. I don't think you should be reaching into components from outside of them.

Comment: @RoyJ What do you mean?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42768150/392102

Comment: Its `this.$refs` and your child component has to include a `<child ref="XYZ" ></child>` this will make it available as `this.$refs.XYZ`

Comment: @Reiner Got confused on how I can implement your examples, weew.

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks for this but still got me stuck on getting the logic. Apologies, I'm still new to Vue.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I have already added `console.log('mounted',this.$children[0])` in `mounted()`, but when I do `console.log('mounted',this.$children[0]).display_table` it returns empty handed. It's empty. How can I use this after mounted? Where should I work next? Sorry, I'm still new to Vue around 3weeks learning.

Comment: Just add your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/vue and share it with a link